# Why wget does not download included videos?

Tags: wget

I use **wget** to download an entire website with all included assets, the problem is that wget does not download included videos.

For example with [this website](http://videohtml5.byethost11.com/index.html), if I execute the following command :

```
wget -q -r ‐‐page-requisites http://videohtml5.byethost11.com/index.html
```

It download almost everything but if you open the web page, you'll see that the video is not downloaded.

I have tried the following options without results:

- -r : for recursion
- --page-requisites : to download all included assets

However if I directly put the link to the video as an option of wget it works :

```
 wget -q -r ‐‐page-requisites http://videohtml5.byethost11.com/movie.mp4
```

But I would like to download everything in one command. I have read the wget manual but I didn't see any other option that could do that. That's why I am asking your help.

EDIT : I change the url to really match my need

**SOLUTION** : Because I am using Windows, I didn't get the latest released which has the fix for the bug. Do not download wget from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm, but use https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video is hosted at a different domain: you need the `-H` parameter.

See the manpage section about spanning hosts: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Spanning-Hosts

== Update ==

It seems wget has a bug preventing to download the `<source>` of the `<video>` tag. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2013-06/msg00070.html

Comment: Ok, I've made an example to clarify the need. If if execute `$ wget -q -r ‐‐page-requisites http://videohtml5.byethost11.com/index.html `on this [website](http://videohtml5.byethost11.com/index.html) it does not download the included video

Comment: I edited my question with an url that really corresponds to my need.

Comment: I add GNU Wget **1.11.4**, it works with **1.16.3** version. Be careful it often happens with command tools like this that normally only exist linux. Updates are sometimes released later on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This works as you expect:

```
wget -H -r --level=1 -k -p http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/

...

drwxr-xr-x 24 root root  4096 Apr 17 10:08 camendesign.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 17 10:08 clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 17 10:08 forum.camendesign.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 13700 May 12  2013 test.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 17 10:08 www.youtube.com
root@test /tmp/test# cd clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/
root@test /tmp/test/clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de# ll
total 5396
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5510872 Feb  9  2010 big_buck_bunny.mp4
```